# Trouble adding user input data to word doc without overriding first input data

Tags: vb.net

I am having a user fill in details in a various test boxes and when they hit add another, it captures all of the details and saves to a word doc in there documents folder.

My problem is that if they fill in the next set after it saves, it overrides the first bit instead of adding it to the bottom of the word doc. It does add what is in sw.Write with the labels but with none of the user inputs.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim sPathUser As String
        sPathUser = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\"
        Dim filepath As String = sPathUser & "Item Creation.doc"

        If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
            System.IO.File.Create(filepath).Dispose()
        End If

        Dim FILE_NAME As String = filepath

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then

            Using objWriter As New IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

                objWriter.Write(vbNewLine + "Please create a new item." _
                                + vbNewLine _
                                + vbNewLine + "Supplier: " + TextBox1.Text _
                                + vbNewLine + "P/N: " + TextBox2.Text _
                                + vbNewLine + "Pine Cost: " + TextBox4.Text + " " + ListBox1.SelectedItem _
                                + vbNewLine + "Suggested Selling Price: " + TextBox5.Text + " " + ListBox2.SelectedItem _
                                + vbNewLine + "Item Name: " + TextBox6.Text _
                                + vbNewLine + "Long Description: " + TextBox7.Text _
                                + vbNewLine + "Item Type: " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem + “     “ + "UoM: " + TextBox8.Text)

                objWriter.Close()
                TextBox1.Clear()
                TextBox2.Clear()
                TextBox3.Clear()
                TextBox4.Clear()
                TextBox5.Clear()
                TextBox6.Clear()
                TextBox7.Clear()
                TextBox8.Clear()
                ListBox1.ClearSelected()
                ListBox2.ClearSelected()
                ComboBox1.SelectedItem = Nothing
            End Using
            MessageBox.Show("Saved to Documents folder. Add next item")

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exist")

        End If

        Dim sr As New StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
        Dim text As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
        sr.Close()
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
        sw.WriteLine(text) ' Add original content back
        sw.Write(vbNewLine _
                        + vbNewLine _
                        + "Supplier: " _
                        + TextBox1.Text _
                        + vbNewLine _
                        + "P/N: " _
                        + TextBox2.Text _
                        + vbNewLine _
                        + "Pine Cost: " _
                        + TextBox4.Text _
                        + " " _
                        + ListBox1.SelectedItem _
                        + vbNewLine _
                        + "Suggested Selling Price: " _
                        + TextBox5.Text _
                        + " " _
                        + ListBox2.SelectedItem _
                        + vbNewLine _
                        + "Item Name: " _
                        + TextBox6.Text _
                        + vbNewLine _
                        + "Long Description: " _
                        + TextBox7.Text _
                        + vbNewLine _
                        + "Item Type: " _
                        + ComboBox1.SelectedItem _
                        + “     “ _
                        + "UoM: " _
                        + TextBox8.Text)
        sw.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: I noticed that in the previous code, you cleared the Text using `TextBox1.Clear()`.

Comment: what happens is that the user inputs into various fields and when they click the button, it saved the entries to a folder displays a message, and when they click ok, all the fields clear. They then fill all the files again and it should write to the same file that it just created, but instead of adding to the bottom, it is overriding with the new entry. i can't seem to get it to add to the bottom instead of completely overriding.